# Sum of Values based on key in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala I have List of Integers

```
val list = List((1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,2,3))    
val sum = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).sum    
val sum2 = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._3)).sum
```

How to perform N values I tried above but its not good way how to sum N values based on key

Also I have tried like this

```
val sum =list.groupBy(_._1).values.sum => error

val sum =list.groupBy(_._1).mapvalues(_.map(_._2).sum (_._3).sum) error
```

Comment: You have a list of tuples, what is the key? The first element? Also, what do you want to sum?

Comment: I want to 1st element as a key remaining all are values based on key I want to perform sum for values

Comment: You want sum based on the location of the element, or sum of all the values? Meaning for the first element `(1, (4, 6))`? Or sum of all values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to convert these tuples to `List[Int]` with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) and then work with them. Your tuples are actually more like lists anyways. Also, as a bonus, you don't need to change your code at all for lists of `Tuple4`, `Tuple5`, etc.

```
import shapeless._, syntax.std.tuple._
val list = List((1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,2,3))
list.map(_.toList) // convert tuples to list
  .groupBy(_.head) // group by first element of list
  .mapValues(_.map(_.tail).map(_.sum).sum) // sums elements of all tails
```

Result is `Map(2 -> 7, 1 -> 10)`.

Comment: But here I can't change to tolist it's giving error

Comment: @Ravi you should use shapeless library as dependency to be able to run this example. You can check github.com/milessabin/shapeless to find, how to do it, if you use SBT or Maven. If you don't use them, you should add shapeless jar to your classpath manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
val sum = list.groupBy(_._1).map(i => (i._1, i._2.map(j => j._1 + j._2 + j._3).sum))
> sum: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 9, 1 -> 12)
```

Since **tuple** can't type safe convert to `List`, need to specify add one by one as `j._1 + j._2 + j._3`.

Answer (score 0):

using the first element in the tuple as the key and the remaining elements as what you need you could do something like this:

```
val list = List((1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,2,3))
list: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3))

val sum = list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k -> v.flatMap(_.productIterator.toList.drop(1).map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])).sum) }
sum: Map[Int, Int] = Map(2 -> 7, 1 -> 10)
```

i know its a bit dirty to do asInstanceOf[Int] but when you do .productIterator you get a Iterator of Any

this will work for any tuple size